# Is python capable of running its separate threads on one process on multiple cores simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a TCP server with multiple clients (around 40), where all the clients are publishing image stream data with 10 fps, and I would like to collect the data from all the clients to one place.

To achieve this, I need a socket connection receiver thread in parallel with the 40 data processing threads, and a thread that collects all the processed data from a shared memory. When a connection is received from a client, I start a new thread for the client to process its data.

Now, I want my system to be scalable (lets say 1000 clients, not 40).

So my question is, if I have so many threads, that one core is running on 100% percent, and still cannot keep up with the tasks, will the scheduler utilize new cores to balance the load, even if all the threads are from one process? Or will my program just slow down and freeze out?

Bonus question: Is the answer specific to python, or this property of threads are general in all programming languages?

Comment: You can switch from threads to processes. Check [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor).

Comment: Yes, I could, but it makes data sharing quite painful. I would like to use global variables with locking, rather then manager.dict which is used in multiprocessing. Also, since what I am doing is i/o bound, I think threads are more appropriate.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-gil/

Comment: @SolomonSlow This post is basically saying that there is this rule of thumb, that when you are doing cpu-bound operations, you should use multiprocessing. However, what I am trying to do is pushing the CPU to its limit by io-bound operations. I get that maybe it is probably a bad idea to put this much load on a single process, because the GIL does not allow any parallelism. So I guess the answer to one of my questions is: one process can use at most 1 core, it will continuously changing threads as fast as it can, and if it cannot keep up with the amount of tasks, it will freeze out. Correct?

Comment: @Daniel, The GIL prevents any single Python process from using more CPU cycles than one CPU can provide. The fact that your process happens to have a lot of threads awaiting I/O at any given instant doesn't change that fact. If what you need more of is CPU cycles (and, assuming of course that your host has more than one CPU), then you'll either have to figure out a way to use `multiprocessing`, or else you'll have to write (at least, the CPU-bound part of) your code in a different language.

Comment: @SolomonSlow So is the only difference between python and (for example) C++ in threading the use of GIL in python? In other words, can C++ use multiple CPU-s in one process by using multiple threads?

Comment: And with python multiprocessing should I create a new Process for each client, or is it better to try to use a ProcessPoolExecutor with a fixed size pool? I guess it is bad to have so many Processes running at once, because each Process has some overhead. And is there an optimal number for ProcessPool size?

Comment: Re, "difference between python and C++," No other language that I know of has anything like Python's GIL. It's a historical accident. `threading` was added to Python back before multi-CPU computers became a thing, and the GIL was an easy way to make `threading` possible. There was no down-side to it so long as computers only had one CPU. But now, Python is stuck with the GIL because the GIL shapes Python's [_memory model_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)) on multi-CPU machines, and a lot of Python programs would stop working if Python were "fixed" to not need it.

Comment: P.S., A language like C++ never needed anything like the GIL because C++ programs don't need the extensive run-time support that Python and other "interpreted" languages need.

Comment: Re, "...new Process for each client..." Sorry, but I am not qualified to answer system architecture questions like that one.